# Network Tracking

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Network Tracking](https://serverfault.com/questions/215981/network-tracking)

Hi all,

I am having fifty workstations which are connected to a windows server 2003 server and the internet is shared from the server .My question is , am i able to implement a tracking mechanism without using any proxy server and track all the web pages which ever visited by an individual workstation connected to a network?If possible how to achieve that kind of tracking mechanism?Some workstations do open their web pages in InPrivate browsing , can we access those browsing history?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg/) and set up a packet sniffing sensor bound to the internet connected NIC on the server. This will capture all inbound and outbound traffic to and from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a switch you can setup a port monitor and sniff with wireshark all the packets.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something in-line if you don't want to use a proxy server.  You can try something like a barracuda webfilter, that's what we used at my old job.  Mostly for web filtering but it tracked all web sites visited as well, so you could run stats on them.  You can also try an open source solution like untangle. [Untangle Web Site](http://www.untangle.com/Web-Filter)

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet would be to set something up like Squid as a transparent proxy to capture all of this traffic. There are a number of things you can do with [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) like this to set it up as a sniffer or special purpose appliance if a proxy really just can't be configured in your network. But from the sounds of it you may want to look into tightening down that network a little more with a hardware or software firewall of some sort which will give you some of these functions.

I have done this at a couple offices using Squid and it's worked out very well.